# Why doesn't show anything in my terminal?

Tags: python, time

I was making a program where my goal is to see in 3 seconds what the highest number the variable "i" can reach, (on my computer), the variables "inicio" and "t" are just used to check if the 3 seconds is already passed or not yet.

But doesn't show anything on my terminal.

This was my code:

```
import time


inicio=0
t=3
i=0

while inicio<=t:
    inicio+=1
    time.sleep(1)
while inicio<=t:
    i+=1
    print(i)
```

Comment: After the first while loop `inicio` is `4` so the second loop never runs because `4<=t` is `False`

Comment: Why did you ask this exact question again?  Didn't you get enough answers the first time?

Comment: @JohnGordon: Darn it stackoverflow. Why can't I see questions that new users have deleted?

Comment: @JohnGordon when I edit the question, nobody answer to my question, so I post the same question two times

Comment: @Mark how I can use two 2 while loops at the same time and execute two different things?

Comment: If the conditions for the two loops are the same, then you _can't_ use them both.  The same condition that made the first loop stop, will keep the second loop from starting.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop you are increasing value of `inicio` variable and when the first loop executes the value of `inicio` is 4. therefore the second loop never executes.

Comment: How can I use the 2 while loops at the same time?

Comment: you can use the 2 while loops but the problem is that in the second loop you chose the wrong condition. if you want that the second loop run forever you can use `while True`

Comment: But I want that the second loop work while the first is looping too at the same time